# Preenchendo um objeto através de outro objeto

Tags: java

estou tentando preencher parâmetros de um objeto através de um outro.
Ao debugar o código ele para nessa parte.

Primeira linha é a 72.

A variável pNumero pega o valor corretamente da JSP. Mas acredito que o problema esta em chegar no Objeto Endereco e setar o valor lá.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue a log do erro "NullPointerException".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
//ENDERECO
supervisor.getEndereco().setNumero(pNumero);
supervisor.getEndereco().setComplemento(pComplemento);
supervisor.getEndereco().setCep(pCEP);
es.criar(supervisor.getEndereco());
```

CONSOLE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at command.CriarSupervisor.executar(CriarSupervisor.java:72)
at controller.ServletController.doExecute(ServletController.java:42)
at controller.ServletController.doPost(ServletController.java:56)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at filter.LogFilter.doFilter(LogFilter.java:55)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at filter.ConnectionFilter.doFilter(ConnectionFilter.java:47)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Pode adicionar o código? Infelizmente nem todos podem ver imagens por restrições de rede.

Comment: Pronto amigo, editei a pergunta.

Comment: O que tem nesse es.criar(supervisor.getEndereco());? ou melhor no es.criar()?

Comment: @Marcondes ele cria o endereço no banco e retorna o id criado.

Comment: es = EnderecoService que chama o EnderecoDAO (criar). Mas o problema é que não esta preenchendo os valores no endereço.

Answer (score 1):

consegui!

Antes de setar os valores em outros objetos eu estanciei eles, pois estava nullos.

```
supervisor.setEndereco(new Endereco());
```